# only redirect a user on login not in registration in firebase javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user) {
    window.location = 'home.html';
  }
});
```

I am trying to make a login and registration page, I have done everything but the problem is I only want to redirect user on when he clicks login in button not on register the above code is not helping it redirects even when registering. Any information you can provide me would be greatly helpful in this matter thank you

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
document.getElementById("login-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  window.location = 'home.html';
});
```

this is just a simple JS code for sending you over to other page when element with `id="login-button"` is clicked.

Comment: the only possible issue with this is that redirectioning will happen on every click

Comment: I want firebase.auth if user is signed in to be applied only when login button or dom is loaded and not in registration button,

Comment: as I said, this will work only when you click on login button, you don't necesarily need to use firebase.auth for redirecitioning

Comment: As I said I want also to check whether user is signed in at dom loaded